# How to detect if a function is asynchronous in Dart

Tags: dart, async-await

How to find out if the function passed is an async function. For example:

```
void checkSync(Function func) {
  if (func is asynchronous) print('async function');
  else print ('not async function');
}
```

Comment: Any function that's async *should* return a `Future`. There's an exceptions where depending on your linter rules, you may be able to make a function with return type `void` that's still `async`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only trust-worthy evidence of being asynchronous is that it returns a future.

There is no good way to check the return type without knowing the number of arguments.
You can try:

```dart
void chcekSync(Function func) {
  if (func is Future Function()) return true;
  if (func is Future Function(Never)) return true;
  if (func is Future Function(Never, Never)) return true;
  if (func is Future Function(Never, Never, Never)) return true;
  // Repeat as long as you want to.
  return false;
}
```

That only works for positional parameters. When Dart gets required named parameters, there will be no way to recognize functions using such.

Obviously, if you know the signature, then it's much easier:

```dart
bool isAsync(dynamic Function(Never, Never) func) => 
   func is Future<dynamic> Function(Never, Never);
```

The `Never` type (or `Null` until Dart gets non-nullable types), is the bottom type of the type hierarchy. That means that `dynamic Function(Never, Never)` is a supertype of *all* two-positional-parameter Functions because of the way function subtyping works.

The above only detects that the function must return a `Future`, not that it *can*.
A function with a return type of `Object` *might* return a future, or it might not. Only calling it can tell for sure.
A function with a return type of `FutureOr<Something>` *might* return a future, and it's ever likely. You might want to treat it as an async function, and if so, change `Future<dynamic>` to `FutureOr<dynamic>` in the type tests above.

Comment: treating the function as async with ```Future.sync(func)``` could help handle both cases....